# How to create Google/Apple map style interface with pinch, zoom, rotate in any direction

Tags: uikit

I am looking to replicate Google Map or Apple Maps style interface with ability to pinch, zoom, scroll right/left, up/down, diagonally, and rotate in any direction but with no Maps. I can likely use UIScrollView but I am not sure how to scroll diagonally or rotate in any direction based on touch. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `UIViuew` property [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) allow you to make all 2d transforms. But to create something like Maps you need to know Open GL well.